# Vaadin. Multiselect grid showing selected checkbox when empty

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

i'm using 7th Vaadin and see the following issue: when grid is empty its multiselect checkbox is turned on:

[image]

How can one fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: I think he'd like the checkbox in the column heading to be either disabled or not checked when the grid is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i can turn off this checkbox using JavaScript directly:

```
String js = "document.getElementById(\"gwt-uid-16\").checked = false;";
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(js);
```

The main possible issue here is the path to the checkbox, especially when there are multiple grids located on the page.

Comment: You could assign an id to your grid and use an x-path to make it a bit safer, something along the lines of:  `js = "document.evaluate(\"//*[@id='mygrid']//th//span[@class='v-grid-select-all-checkbox']/input[@type='checkbox']\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.checked=false;"`

Comment: I was going to suggest that using the gwt-uid-16 id wasn't a good idea, but @Morfic beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to hide it when there are no items, and show it when there are with a bit of *hacking* and [theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html) update. The hacks are required because even if the checkbox is hidden, the listener is still triggered when clicking that space, so after removing all items, clicking on it, and adding new items it may appear checked even if there is no real selection.

1) **Theme**

```css
.invisible-select-all-checkbox .v-grid-select-all-checkbox {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

2) **Code**

```java
public class GridWithDisabledSelectAllCheckbox extends VerticalLayout {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GridWithDisabledSelectAllCheckbox.class);

    public GridWithDisabledSelectAllCheckbox() {
        // basic grid setup with multiple selection
        BeanItemContainer<Person> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(Person.class);
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
        grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.MULTI);

        // listen for changes in the container
        container.addItemSetChangeListener(event -> {
            if (event.getContainer().size() == 0) {
                // no more items, hide the checkbox
                grid.addStyleName("invisible-select-all-checkbox");
            } else {
                // oo, items, show the checkbox
                grid.removeStyleName("invisible-select-all-checkbox");
            }

            if (grid.getSelectedRows().isEmpty()) {
                // although the checkbox is hidden, the listener is still triggered when clicking the header
                // thus, when adding items after removing all of them, it may appear checked which is not nice.
                // to bypass this we can reset the selection state, if there was nothing previously selected
                // if there were items in the grid but they were not selected, it won't change anything so we should be safe
                grid.getSelectionModel().reset();
            }
        });

        // add some dummy data
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            container.addBean(new Person(i));
        }

        HorizontalLayout buttonsLayout = new HorizontalLayout();

        // add some other dummy data
        buttonsLayout.addComponent(new Button("Add", event -> container.addItem(new Person(container.size()))));

        buttonsLayout.addComponent(new Button("Remove", event -> {
            // remove selected items, if any
            if (!grid.getSelectedRows().isEmpty()) {
                new ArrayList<>(grid.getSelectedRows()).forEach(row -> {
                    // unfortunately, it seems that removing a row doesn't also deselect it
                    // so the hack for resetting the selection is not complete without this part
                    grid.deselect(row);
                    container.removeItem(row);
                });
            }
        }));

        addComponent(grid);
        addComponent(buttonsLayout);
    }

    // basic bean
    public static class Person {
        private String name;
        private String surname;

        public Person(int index) {
            this.name = "name " + index;
            this.surname = "surname" + index;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }
    }
}
```

3) **Result**

[image: Grid hack for multi row selection]

Comment: Thanx a lot for your reply. But it seems i've found more simple solution. i'm going to post it separately.

Comment: @user1053031 no problem, I'm glad you did. One thing you may want to note that in your solution depending on your requirements, is that the checkbox is still checkable, but that should not be a big issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
container.addItemSetChangeListener(event -> {
            if (event.getContainer().size() == 0) {
                    getSelectionModel().reset();
                    setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.NONE);
                } else {
                    getSelectionModel().reset();
                    setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
                }
        });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Please describe this with more details

Comment: Hi! thanx for your reply. Actually i don't work on this project anymore so can't be more specific at this moment